# change </br> to \n in php without damaging database

Tags: php, jquery

I create a jquery to add `</br>` when we click `enter`

```
$('.description').keyup(function (e){
                if(e.keyCode == 13){
                    var curr = getCaret(this);
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var end = val.length;

                    $(this).val( val.substr(0, curr) + '</br>' + val.substr(curr, end));
                }

            });
function getCaret(el) { 
            if (el.selectionStart) { 
                return el.selectionStart; 
            } else if (document.selection) { 
                el.focus(); 

                var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
                if (r == null) { 
                    return 0; 
                } 

                var re = el.createTextRange(), 
                rc = re.duplicate(); 
                re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
                rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

                return rc.text.length; 
            }  
            return 0; 
        }
```

it show in text area like below

```
- This is top page design
</br>
- This 
</br>
- is
</br>
- test
</br>
- for
</br>
br 
</br>
changing
</br>
```

I want to hide `</br>` in that text area
so i use jquery

```
var str = $('.meeting-data-container .description').val();
    $('.meeting-data-container .description').val(str.replace("</br>", "\n"));
```

It hide  and create new line, 
but when I save in database it save `space` instead of `</br>`
I want to save data without damaging `</br>` from database

Comment: Try [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when you save from textarea.

Comment: Don't use `\n`, use `\r\n`, or try what bansi suggested

Comment: i think it doesn't matter </br> or <br/>.

Comment: How to user nl2br for input into database or fetching data from database?

Comment: $insertdata = mysql_real_escape_string($string); for insert data